# how to declare a dictionary using another variable

Tags: ansible

I need to declare a dictionary from ansible facts. the issue is i need to pass on a string value to create this dictionary. but when i try to pass this variable it creates a string rather than a dictionary.

I tried using set_facts also to create the variable still not able to find the solution.

```
  - name: get part name
    set_fact:
      device_name: "nvme1n1"

  - setup:
      filter:
        ansible_devices
    register: detail

  - set_fact:
      part_dict: "{{detail.ansible_facts.ansible_devices.{{device_name}}.partitions}}"

  - debug:
      var: part_dict
```

When i use the above code the output is a string

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.95.198.103] => {
    "part_dict": "detail.ansible_facts.ansible_devices.\"nvme1n1\".partitions"
}
```

but when i just hardcode the device name then i get the dictionary. i just need to how do i correct the syntax so i can get the dictionary by passing the key as a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map elements can be accessed through different syntax:

**Option 1:**

`variable.element1.element2`

**Option2:**

`variable['element1']['element2']`

**Mix:**

`variable['element1'].element2`

In your case, you simply have to slighly change the syntax so that ansible does not get confused (or even fires an error with the test I made with ansible 2.7.8 + Jinja 2.10)

```
part_dict: "{{ detail.ansible_facts.ansible_devices[device_name].partitions }}"
```

Comment: great thanks it worked like charm. thank you for saving my day.